# How does this YouTube latest video code work?

Tags: youtube-api

I used some code to find the latest video from a specific channel, I have a basic idea of how it works, but I’m not sure how it sources the video. If someone could explain that'd be great

```
<!--Latest video-->
    <h1 class="title"> Latest video </h1>
    <div id="static_video"></div>
    <!--Source the latest vdeo-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showVideo(response) {
            if(response.data && response.data.items) {
                var items = response.data.items;
                if(items.length>0) {
                    var item = items[0];
                    var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                    console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                    var video = "<iframe width='720' height='480' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                    $('#static_video').html(video);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC9DiuD3z0btMOAMG_FvDRag/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
```

It can be seen [here](http://inthelytesky.com/videos.html)

Another help would be, how can I show all the videos, with a search box to, well search through them. Sorry if I seem greedy but it would be a MASSIVE help if some one could explain.

EDIT: Bump, I don't like bumping, but I need this answered, please help me!

Comment: don't understand : find the latest video from a specific video

Comment: Ah made a typo,  meant a video from a specific channel,  will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the API V2 is deprecated, you need to use the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) with the ressource [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

You need an API Key, follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register) to get one.

Use this parameters to get the lastest upload of the channel :

```
part: 'snippet' or 'id'
channelId: 'UC9DiuD3z0btMOAMG_FvDRag'
maxResults: 1
order: date
```

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId=UC9DiuD3z0btMOAMG_FvDRag&maxResults=1&order=date&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The  output :

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/9r2l5FZB6-ysy9_0d37qYA5Kg8I\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "WH8U2NQ_fnA"
   }
  }
```

Then you have the last video ID of the channel. 
After that, you need to use the [YouTube API player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=FR). 
A live example to show you how the player works : http://jsbin.com/vajobawiba/1/edit?html,js,output

You just need to copy that code with the video ID you get from the previous step !

**Example :**

Add this line at the end of the body in your index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

And there is the javascript example:

```
function googleApiClientReady() {
    var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        youtubeId,
        request;
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'id',
            channelId: 'UC9DiuD3z0btMOAMG_FvDRag',
            maxResults: 1,
            order: date
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
            if(response.pageInfo.totalResults != 0) {
                youtubeId = response.result.items[0].id.videoId;
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this seems greedy, but could you show me an example of the request code?

Comment: @EverlessDrop41 add you an example